# Is controlling for cluster good enough in an analysis with a clustered sample?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, sampling, multilevel-analysis, cluster-sample

I'm trying to understand how sampling design affects analyses and I'm a little confused about how to adjust for clustering. From what I've read, when you have a clustered sample you are supposed to calculate (or estimate from previous research) a design effect for use in both the power calculation and the standard error for any hypothesis tests.
In cases where researchers are only interested in the micro-units (i.e. they don't want to make inferences about the clusters) and they thus choose not to use a multilevel model, I've noticed that most seem to just include dummy-coded regressors in a multiple regression model to control for the effect of cluster.
Is this sufficient, or is it inferior to adjusting the standard error in the analysis by the design effect?